# Why is my Virtual Host setup ignored?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

in `/srv/www/vhosts/myproject.de/subdomains/trac/conf` my **vhost.conf** file is located: http://pastebin.com/xTgdnkvr

However apache seems to ignore this setup. Every http request is routed to `/srv/www/vhosts/myproject.de/subdomains/trac/httpdocs` instead of to `/srv/www/vhosts/myproject.de/subdomains/trac/htdocs`.

After making changes to the vhost file I always reconfigure it and restart httpd from command line.

Any idea what might be wrong? Maybe some other config overwrites it?

Comment: Is that the only vhost definition on your server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because another configuration file / directive is overriding the one you think the system should be using.

Computers only do what they're told, so somewhere you must be telling it that you want "httpdocs" instead of "htdocs".  `grep` around in your Apache configuration directory for the httpdocs path and work from there.

Comment: I found a httpd.include that actually overwrites my vhost.conf